# Why this Desktop notification code is not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webkit

I am using the below code to show notification. But it is not working. Please help me on this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  if (window.webkitNotifications.checkPermission() == 0) {
       var popup = window.webkitNotifications.createNotification
                    ("", "Notifier", "Properties will be displayed like this");
       popup.show();
  } 
 });
```

With the above code I could not see any notification.

Comment: Have you done the confirmation for user of allowing notifications?

Comment: @zvona Yes I have checked with that also.. Please have a look at updated Question

Comment: Which part isn't working? the checkPermission conditional or the createnotification method call?

Comment: What does the Chrome console tell you ?

Comment: Yes In log it is showing permission denied even after giving permission.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see you're using `$(document).ready()` and perhaps you are also using that kind of thing to request for permission.  This cannot be done and must be requested on a user action like the click of a button:

> However, it's **very important** to remember that the `requestPermission` method only works in event handlers triggered by a user action, like mouse or keyboard events, in order to avoid unsolicited infobars. In this case, the user action is the click on the button with id "show_button".

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/notifications/quick/#toc-step3

Double check your `window.webkitNotifications.checkPermission()` value and you might find it's not actually `0` unless you request under the condition of a user action.